# Possible to create other forms based on a form submission?

Tags: 2010, workflow, infopath

I am working on a problem where I need to generate **tags** automatically based upon information that users fill out in a **form**. I am working with Office 2010.

**Workflow:** I have a repeating table for the user to fill in the information that is needed, however many times they need to add it. Then, based on the information provided, different forms would be created.

My plan was to create the **template forms using InfoPath**, and then use SharePoint to carry out the generation process. Is this possible with SharePoint/InfoPath, or am I expecting too much?